# How To Set A Screen Timeout To Less Than 5 Seconds In Android?

Tags: java, android

I am building a lock screen app for Android. At present I am able to implement the locking functionality using Device Admin API. But the problem is that if I lock the device using this strategy it disables the fingerprint the next time user tries to unlock the phone.

To overcome this I am trying use the Screen timeout(by setting it to a lower value). My plan is to:

1. Set a screen timeout to 3 Seconds.
2. Show a black Full screen activity during this time.

However when I try to set screentimeout to 5 Seconds it doesnt seem to be working. This is the code that I am using

```
public void timeLock() {
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (Settings.System.canWrite(ctx)) {
                // Do stuff here
                int time = 5000;
                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, time);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + ctx.getPackageName()));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    }
```